# Transferring an object from a Realm database to another UITabBar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, uitabbar

Tell me, please, I'm trying to solve the problem of transferring an instance of a class to another controller using the Realm database.

I have a main controller that stores objects according to the model the following data:

```swift
class Route: Object {
    @objc dynamic var routeImage: Data?
    @objc dynamic var routeName: String?
    @objc dynamic var numberOfPersons = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var dateOfDeparture: String?
    @objc dynamic var dateOfArrival: String?
    let placeToVisit = List<Place>()
    let person = List<Person>()
}
```

In the controller to which I need to transfer this data, I created

```swift
var currentRoute: Route!
```

In the Storyboard, I specified the identifier "showDetail" from the controller cell to the UITabBar, and in the main controller, I created a method:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
       guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}

       let newPlaceVC = segue.destination as! InformationViewController
           newPlaceVC.currentRoute = routes[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

> Error I got:

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x111ed8b10) to 'Organizer_Tourist.InformationViewController' (0x108dd0a70).
2019-10-07 14:30:35.626853+0800 Organizer Tourist[5467:2618892] Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x111ed8b10) to 'Organizer_Tourist.InformationViewController' (0x108dd0a70).
(lldb)
```

But it is not valid, the application crashes by tap on the cell. I suppose this would work if there was not a tabBar, but a regular table, view controllers. I was looking for solutions and all I came across was implementation through singleton. Now I have a lot of questions, but will this really be the right decision? People say this violates the "modularity" of the application and carries its own problems. The question is how is this done through singleton? What to consider, where to start? Which method is worth editing?

Comment: What does the error say, when you tap on cell? Please add error message to your question.

Comment: Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x111ed8b10) to 'Organizer_Tourist.InformationViewController' (0x108dd0a70).
2019-10-07 14:30:35.626853+0800 Organizer Tourist[5467:2618892] Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x111ed8b10) to 'Organizer_Tourist.InformationViewController' (0x108dd0a70).
(lldb)

Answer (score 1):

Error said what is happening:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController'

You are trying to cast `segue.destination` to typo `InformationViewController` which is not.

If you embed your `InformationViewController` in `UITabBarController` so you need to cast to your `UITabBarController` rather than `InformationViewController`.

Try something like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
   guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

   let tabBarController = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
   UserSelectedRoute.shared.selectedRoute = routes[indexPath.row]
}
```

If you want to pass current selected route to `InformationViewController` you can create singleton object which will be hold current route

```
final class UserSelectedRoute {

    private init() { }

    static var shared = UserSelectedRoute()

    var selectedRoute: Route?
}
```

And then in your `InformationViewController` you can have something like:

`var currentRoute = UserSelectedRoute.shared.selectedRoute`

**Hope this will help you!**

Comment: Does it mean that I need to create a new file for the tabbar class and specify the destination for this class? Now I have 5 view controllers, which I contain in tabBar, but I haven't got file that describes tabBar. And I can specify segue.destination as! "TabBarController" for example?

Comment: @StGregor1996 I edit my answer, just cast to `UITabBarController` it should work fine

Comment: Ok, but I have new error =(
Value of type 'UITabBarController' has no member 'currentRoute'

Comment: I see a problem, i add basic example of Singleton object

Comment: I followed all your recommendations, but I get an empty object in InformationViewController =( 
Unexpectedly found nil... 
I try to get object from database and append new value to property placeToVisit<Place>() in another VC. Value is typo Place